# Error when trying to add a new field to attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have my attribute table open, in edit mode and am trying to add a new column. the dialogue box open but I am unable to select the type" for the field and then when I press OK it gives "Failed to add field 'people' of type ''. Is the field name unique?".

I also opened the properties of the layer to try but there the add and delete columns are both grayed out.

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that each thread should be limited to one specific question only. You can check our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information. I've removed the second question.

Comment: Maybe you can use the Table Manager plugin instead. I've had more success with that.

Comment: What format is your layer?